# git: finding which merge brough commit into the current branch

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a number of branches, which are periodically merged, i.e. we can have A, which is merged into B, then B into C, then A into D and D into C, etc. Suppose I have a commit X, which I know was originally introduces in A, and then merged into C somehow (I can see it when I do git log C). Is there a way to find out which merge (which merge commit) brought the commit X into the branch C?

Comment: Does it help to `git grep X at all ?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant not sure how git grep would be helpful, could you ebalorate? I can't grep for specific text in file/commit since the commit I'm looking for makes ton of small changes, and almost any pattern there will be also in some other commits with high probability.

Answer (score 5):

Usually I do something like the following:

```
git log --oneline --ancestry-path --merges <commit-of-interest>..C
```

The `--ancestry-path` argument is the key here: it causes git to only show commits that are both a descendant of `<commit-of-interest>` AND an ancestor of `C`.  The `--merges` option filters the resulting list further to only show merge commits.

Each of the printed merges falls into one of the following categories:

- the merge brought `<commit-of-interest>` into a branch
- the merge brought a different branch into a branch that already has `<commit-of-interest>`
- both parent branches already had `<commit-of-interest>`

The first category is the one you're interested in.  You can usually tell which category the merge is in by looking at the commit subject line.  Start at the bottom of the list; the oldest merges are the most likely to be in the first category.

It's technically possible to write a script to filter out merges in the second and third categories (just test to see if `<commit-of-interest>` is reachable by the merge's first parent), but I've never found it to be necessary.

If you need to do a more in-depth study of the commit history then I recommend looking at the history graph:

```
git log --oneline --graph --color --decorate \
    --ancestry-path <commit-of-interest>..C
```

You may want to toss in `--boundary` too, although sometimes that adds too much noise.  You could use `gitk`, but unfortunately the graph it draws doesn't show parentage in the correct order (`gitk` might draw the edge between a merge and its second parent on the left; `git log --graph` always draws the second parent edge on the right).

Comment: Unfortunately, what I'm getting from this is 1500+ lines of commits looking like this:

`| | * 4b4079b Merge pull request #1234 from username/bug3456`

which isn't a lot of help. Now, the last line is the merge with commit I'm looking for, but it says when this commit was merged into  another branch, into which it was originally brought, but not when it got into C and which merge did it...

Comment: @StasM: The default merge commit message is "Merge branch 'foo'" (if merging `foo` into `master`) or "Merge branch 'foo' into bar" (if merging `foo` into `bar`).  If none/few of your merge commits are like this, then it might be tough -- you'll probably have to write a script to filter out merges in the second two categories I mentioned.  In my situation, merge commits almost always have the default format so grepping for "into C" and finding the last match would locate the merge of interest in all of the repositories I use.

Comment: Awesome, this helped me debug a "too early merge" issue we had over here. Thanks a lot!